# Knockout: Change observable value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, observable

I use a requirejs/crossroads setup.

This is my bootstrapping with some global properties:

```
ko.applyBindings({
    route: router.currentRoute,
    user: {
        ...
    },
    ...
    loading: ko.observable(false),
    setLoadingState: function(newState) {
        this.loading(newState);
    }
});
```

When calling the `setLoadingState` function from components (passed via params), it tells me that `loading` is not a function/`undefined`.

What's the correct way of implementing such mechanisms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that in your (simplified?) example, you don't need an additional method since it only forwards to `loading`, which can be called directly.

---

Either use a class like pattern to make sure `this` refers to your view model like so:

```js
var MyApp = function(router) {
  this.route = router.currentRoute,
  this.loading = ko.observable(false);
};

MyApp.prototype.setLoadingState = function(newState) {
    this.loading(newState);
};


ko.applyBindings(new MyApp(router));
```

(you can also use the more modern `class` syntax)

or, use plain objects via a "factory" function:

```js
var MyApp = function(router) {
  var route = router.currentRoute,
  var loading = ko.observable(false);
  var setLoadingState = function(newState) {
    loading(newState);
  };
  
  // Expose what you want to expose:
  return {
    loading: loading,
    setLoadingState: setLoadingState
  };
};

ko.applyBindings(MyApp(router));
```

Comment: Important: I can just call it directly, there's no need of the classes. Do you want to change the order of your examples? Maybe someone else won't notice. Thanks a lot for your different solutions.